# Filling Input=text with Select Options

Tags: jquery, select, input

I'm trying to fill an input form with different select box, for example:

(The example below does not work at all )

http://jsfiddle.net/K35er/1/
(The example above does not work at all )

but the goal is to get all the values in the input but in this format :

```
1/2 R3
```

where 1 is #select , 2 is #select2 & R3 is #select3

is this possible??

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `.val()` to get the value of the selected option. In you `onchange` handler you need something like below,

```
$(".myselect").change(function () {
    $("#hiddenNOT").val($('#select').val() + '/' + $('#select2').val() + ' ' + $('#selec3').val());
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/K35er/3/

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/K35er/5/

HTML

```
<select id="select1">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>    
</select>

<select id="select2">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>    
</select>

<select id="select3">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>    
</select>

<input type='text' id='hiddenNOT' value=''/>
```

JavaScript

```
$("select").change(function () {
    $("#hiddenNOT").val($('#select1').val() + '/' + $('#select2').val() + ' R' + $('#select3').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").change(function () {

    $("#hiddenNOT").val(
           $("#select").val()+'/'+
           $("#select2").val()+'R'+
           $("#selec3").val()
         );
});
```